# Removing multiple characters from string field using Field Calculator Python Parser?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

Is it possible to remove more than 1 character from a string in a field using the field calculator?

I know

```
!file!.replace(" ","")
```

removes spaces in a string, but is it possible to remove spaces and other characters such as "!", "?", "," all at once?

I have also tried:

*Pre Logic Script:*

```
def replChars(Name):
    replaceChars = ["!","?",","]
    for char in replaceChars:
        Name.replace(char,"")
```

*Field* =

```
replChars(!NH_NAME!)
```

Comment: This one is a pure Python question that can be researched at [so]. Try putting your function into a test Python script to see that.

Comment: How is it a pure python question? It's not talking about a script, it's simply asking about the python parser within the field calculator. I see many questions like this.

Comment: I'm going to re-open because the exclamation mark replacement may require more than pure Python.  I would still recommend researching this at [so] too.

Comment: Thank you. This question is definitely not relevant to pure python, lol.

Comment: Yes, you can do this in ArcMap field calculator with the Python parser.  I would probably try it with regex.

Comment: you should be using an update cursor

Comment: There could be any number of fancy ways to do this, I do a replace for each: !file!.replace(" ","").replace("!","").replace(" ","").replace("?",""). PolyGeo is correct, this is a python question more than an ArcGis question.

Comment: the `!` may cause problems and may need to be escaped due to arcpy using `!` to identify field names

Comment: True @Midavalo. The ? too.

Comment: I think this would work if you changed the last line to `Name = Name.replace(char, "")` and I think you also need to return the `Name` variable.  The way you have it is not properly chaining the string replacements.

Comment: if you want to loop, don't reuse the same variable each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your single line

```
!file!.replace(" ","")
```

can be added to by including more `.replace()`

```
!file!.replace(" ","").replace("?","").replace(",","").replace(chr(33),"")
```

and so on.  You may need to escape some of the characters, or use their `chr()` code if the field calculator doesn't like them.  `chr(33)` in my example replaces the `!`.

Chr codes can be retrieved from: http://www.ascii-code.com/ or by opening the python window in ArcMap and typing `ord("!")`, for example, or whatever character you want to find into `ord()`.

Comment: Thank you for this. Where can I get a list of chr codes?

Comment: They're ASCII codes, try http://www.ascii-code.com/

Comment: or in the python window type `ord("!")` which will return the `chr()` code `33`.  Put whatever character you want to find into `ord()`

Comment: This worked wonderfully! I love the simplicity of it! I did not know adding more `.replace()` after the first one was possible. Thank you so very much!

Comment: Could the down-voter please leave a comment?

Answer (score 6):

Even though this question can be considered off topic I though I would make a suggestion.

Try using the [Python re module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) in the Field Calculator.  Here is a simple example used in the ArcMap field calculator.

**Pre-Logic Script Code**

```
 import re
 def repChar(strg)
     regexChars = '[!@$*#]'
     line = re.sub(regexChars,'',x)
     return line
```

**Field**

```
repChar(strg)
```

I know this isn't a very detailed excample but it's all I have time for at the moment.

Comment: Does the field calculator recognize imported modules?

Comment: Yes it does. I've done this many times with no problem.. you don't want to get too complex as there's no debugging though.

Answer (score 2):

It's not pretty, but

```
''.join([x for x in list(!file!) if x not in ["!","@","$"]])
```

should remove any single character you specify in the list, and return the resulting characters as a string (the "etc" in your example wouldn't work, however).